# Java program that reads int from keyboard (with exceptions) - is there a more efficient way?

Tags: java, exception

I'm new to Java and I want to make a program that reads an int from keyboard. If you enter a non-int value, it throws an exception and reads again until you enter an int.
The code is:

```
package Exceptie;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=0;

        while(n==0){
            try {
                n=Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                if (n==0) break;
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("not int, read again");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you suggest an approach that doesn't require n to be initialized?

Comment: That Kind of questions is better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways this is the simple way, you can use another `boolean` variable for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;//no need to initialize n
    boolean b = false;
    while (!b) {//repeat until b = true
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            if (n == 0) {
                b = true;//if n == 0 then b = true
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("not int, read again");
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have used `Boolean` instead of an integer. Try this.

```
 package Exceptie;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        boolean isInt = false;
        while(!isInt){
            try {
                n=Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                isInt = true;
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("not int, read again");
            }
        }
    }
}
```